# How to create an array using for loop while by keeping range fixed in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
newarray = [x + 0.5 for x in range(1, 10)]
```

this code will give me following result:

```
newarray
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]
```

Instead of adding 0.5 with x I want to increase my x by 0.5 for each 1 increment of x. The output suppose to be

```
newarray=[0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5......5.5].
```

Keep in mind that my range must be fix in 1 to 10. What can be better approach to make that?

Answer (score 1):

```
[0.5 * x for x in range(1, 12)]
```

Will do the thing, I'm afraid generating that array with `range(1, 10)` is impossible

Comment: Maybe you should write the desired result completely @TanvirHossain

Comment: result=[0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5]...it should not start from 0.

Comment: Look, `range(1, 10)` will give you a list of 9 values, and you want a list with 11 ones. @TanvirHossain

Comment: if I keep my range (0,10) is it possible to start my array from 0.5?

Comment: `0, 10`? Yes, `[(x + 1) * 0.5 for x in range(0, 10)]`